# Determine the dynamics (SDE) of X_t^4

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose X and Y evolve according to:

dXt= (2 + 5t + Xt)dt + 3 dz_1t

dYt= 4Ytdt + 8Ytdz_1t + 6dz_2t

where z_1t and z_2t are Brownian motions with (dz_1t )(dz_2t )=0.1dt

Can you give me some starting point how to transform the equations to the initial SDE in order to apply the Ito's lemma?

Comment: But you say you only want to look at $X_t^4$ so why do you state $Y_t$? Is there more to this question?

Comment: because the is the first sub-question the additional questions are for a.) X^4t b.) e^Xt c.) XtYt d.)X^4tYt

Comment: I am good but not that good to know the other questions. I did realise that it was part of a larger question. Just in case you was going to add the other parts you either state in full or split the questions out.

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 0):

$$
df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}dt + \frac{\partial f}{\partial X_t}dX_t + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial X_t^2}dX_t^2
$$
That's Ito's

thus
$$
dX_t^4 = \frac{\partial }{\partial X_t}\left(X_t^4\right)dX_t + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial X_t^2}\left(X_t^4\right)dX_t^2
$$
Compute the partials first then use the fact that $\left(dz_t^1\right)^2 = dt$ to compute the sde. Then do a similar process for all the above, except you have to use the modified Ito for multivariable when you have to it for $f\left(X_t,Y_t\right)$.